Gazebo does not calculate dynamics when joint_trajectory_controller with position command_interface is used
I was wondering why Gazebo does not calculate dynamics (velocity, acceleration, effort) when JointTrajectoryController is used with
command_interfaces:
      - position



When I used
command_interfaces:
      - effort

I was able to see both velocity and effort calculated correctly.


Is there any way to make Gazebo calculate these variables even if their values are not used by the joint_trajectory_controller?

No this is not possible. gazebo_ros2_control is implemented in a way that it overrides the position value, without calling the physics engine behind it. See this issue for more information, or this PR for a suggestion of adding position-controlled interface what would solve your issue as well.
